# TypeError: type 'range' is not an acceptable base type

Tags: python, range, multimethod

Could you please tell me what is wrong with this code?

```py
from multimethod import multimethod
from typing import Iterable

@multimethod
def foo(x: Iterable[Iterable]):
    print(x)

@multimethod
def foo(x):
    print(x)

foo([range(1), range(2)])
```

The error I get is:

```
TypeError: type 'range' is not an acceptable base type
```

Interestingly, these snippets do work:

```py
from multimethod import multimethod

@multimethod
def foo(x):
    print(x)

foo([range(1), range(2)])
```

or

```py
from multimethod import multimethod
from typing import Iterable

@multimethod
def foo(x: Iterable):
    print(x)

@multimethod
def foo(x):
    print(x)

foo([range(1), range(2)])
```

---

As a little bit of context, what I am trying to do is build a hierarchy and dispatch different functions depending on what types an `Iterable` holds:

```py
from multimethod import multimethod
from typing import Generator, Iterable
import string

def gen(stop):
    i = 0
    for c in string.ascii_lowercase:
        if i < stop:
            i += 1
            yield c

@multimethod
def bar(x: Iterable[range]):
    print('bar(x: Iterable[range]')

@multimethod
def bar(x: Iterable[Generator]):
    print('bar(x: Generator)')

@multimethod
def bar(x: Iterable[Iterable]):
    print('bar(x: Iterable)')


#bar([range(1), range(2)])
bar([gen(2), gen(3)])
bar([[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3]])
```